# Connect to a device with WiFi, but use 4G for Internet

Tags: wi-fi, 4g

As the title states, is there a way to connect to a WiFi device (my drone), yet use another app on 4G? Right now when I'm connected to my drone using WiFi, I can't use 4G, but is there a work around?

Comment: what is your android version ,there is a stock feature to do this when the wifi hotspot your connected to have no internet access but this feature is only on new versions only I can't tell for sure which version

Answer (score 0):

Samsung devices have a direct connect with option via Wi-Fi (Wi-Fi Direct), it acts as a hotspot for your other devices but uses your mobile data for internet. Other manufacturers and carriers offer similar features also, take a peek in your settings and see what you've got.

Comment: It's Android 5.1 on a Motorola Droid Turbo. I browsed the settings but don't see anything that stands out. Would it be under cell data or wifi?

Comment: http://www.verizonwireless.com/support/knowledge-base-117249/

Comment: I see the wifi direct but cannot connect to my drone using it. It doesn't find the Drone once it's powered, but my wifi scan finds it fine. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: Your drone may not be capable of seeing it, if it functions for other devices you're looking at a problem with the drone, not your phone.

Comment: Well dang. Any other ideas?

Comment: Try changing the encryption type of your Wi-Fi hotspot, your drone may see it if you set it to wep or open